# What Changes need in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

how i changes in .htaccess file??

http://www.mydomain.com/index.htm
all redirect to:
http://www.mydomain.com/

Comment: What have you tried? And what failed while you were trying? What is the actual question?

Comment: Besides - **few** surelly means **more than one**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```